# Log files or output not being produced in process is started - Python

Tags: python, process, command, scheduled-tasks

I'm using `Popen` from `subprocess` to start a command line tool, which starts a Java Scheduler for me:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys

cmd = "java -Xmx600m -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.scheduler.app.main config.properties"
scheduler = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                  stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
if scheduler.pid is not None:
   print("Scheduler started with PID: %s" % scheduler.pid)
   logfile = open('logfile', 'w')
   for line in scheduler.stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        logfile.write(line)
   scheduler.wait()
```

The only output I get is:

```
Scheduler started with PID: 9169
```

Similar commands are started in a similar fashion. When I do: `ps aux | grep java` I see those processes have started:

```
psouzamora       9169   0.0  0.0        0      0 s001  Z+    9:26AM   0:00.00 (java)
psouzamora       9170   0.0  0.0        0      0 s001  Z+    9:26AM   0:00.00 (java)
psouzamora       9171   0.0  0.0        0      0 s001  Z+    9:26AM   0:00.00 (java)
psouzamora       9421   0.0  0.0  2445076    804 s017  S+    9:29AM   0:00.00 grep java
psouzamora       9168   0.0  0.0        0      0 s001  Z+    9:26AM   0:00.00 (java)
```

However, I don't see any output, or log files being generated. The program ends correctly and no zombie processes are left. However, I don't see any output being generated, nor the log files.

When I execute the same command from the terminal, I get:

```
2015-11-03 09:34:36.269 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] DEBUG c.c.u.ConfigHandler - property file = staging.properties
2015-11-03 09:34:36.337 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] INFO  o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2015-11-03 09:34:36.343 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] INFO  o.q.s.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
2015-11-03 09:34:36.363 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] INFO  o.q.c.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2015-11-03 09:34:36.365 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] INFO  o.q.c.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
2015-11-03 09:34:36.366 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] INFO  o.q.s.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
2015-11-03 09:34:36.367 ${sys:ipaddr} 9965 [main] INFO  o.q.c.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

looking into the `logs` directory I see `app-2015-11-03.09-34-36.log` which is supposed to be there. I wonder what's going on. The command being executed is correct. The `java` process being started is supposed to keep running until it's killed by the framework that started the process in first place. Could someone give me some light in what's going on?
I've updated my question with a piece of code I've added in order to read the pipes. Nothing is being outputted and the `logfile` is empty.

Comment: Are you reading the pipes from the command that you execute? What do they say?

Comment: @tdelaney I've updated my question. Please take a look. The pipes don't display anything.

Comment: You aren't reading `stderr`. Try `stderr=STDOUT` to see if more info is available.

Comment: @tdelaney stderr is also outputting nothing...

Comment: What about `scheduler.returncode`? Java may have disliked a parameter and terminated.